# Why is Higgs particle detected much later than top quark when it's lighter?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, higgs, large-hadron-collider, particle-detectors

The Higgs boson is lighter than the top quark. But the top quark was discovered in the mid-1990s where the Higgs boson escaped detection for two more decades. So if the energy has already been achieved to produce Higgs boson, why did it escape detection so far?

I understand that the couplings of Higgs boson to fermions is small and doesn't interact with the detector appreciably.

*Does it mean that in LHC, with the increase in energy, the Higgs coupling increased and we finally detected Higgs?*

Comment: Have a look at this paper by CMS on the difficulties of detecting the Higgs   in fermion couplings , in contrast to ZZ, WW and γγ https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4362.pdf

Comment: I asked a similar question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/246841/why-did-it-take-so-long-to-find-the-higgs).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With both particles you cannot detect them within their own lifetimes, only look at what they decay into. The top decays to a b jet and W (which can then become fermion anti-fermion or leptons) and is fairly distinctive. The dominant Higgs decay, however, is to two b jets. B jets are very common within the LHC and we cannot infer from two b jets that a Higgs detection has been made.

It's all about the statistics. With the top, its decay mode was distinctive enough that fewer events were needed before a statistically significant signal was seen above the background, whereas the Higgs needed many more events.

Comment: Care to contrast the relative production cross-sections?

Comment: They basically differ by 2 orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

The Higgs being a scalar uncharged particle has the same quantum numbers as the vacuum, making it much harder to detect.

Comment: I didn’t down vote, but assuming your answer is factually correct, I’m guessing the down vote came from having absolutely no idea what 90% of those words mean.

Comment: Just to note it, I don't think that this answer's really going to explain much to most readers without elaboration.  It seems like people who aren't already very familiar with QM won't understand it, while people who are already very familiar with QM already know the answer to this question.  This could be improved by expanding on why having the same quantum numbers as the vacuum matters; I mean, that clearly _sounds_ like a neat observation, but what real world effect does it have, in terms that a layman could understand?